# How to mount pcsc from macos to linux docker container

Tags: docker, pcsc

Mac os has internal implementation of PC/SC to work with smart cards (process `/System/Library/Frameworks/PCSC.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.ctkpcscd.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.ctkpcscd`). Linux can work with PC/SC via installing lib [PCSC lite](https://pcsclite.apdu.fr/).

If host system and docker container is linux, than docker container can work with smart card. Need to install on host system pcsc lite, and pass volume pcscd.comm to docker container. `docker run ... -v /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm:/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm`.

Is it possible to work with smart card in docker container on linux, if host system is mac os? What need to mount?